# Git - Branching Basics

Tags: branch, git-branch

Lets say there exists a MASTER repository with 2 different branches(branch A and branch B) already created for it. I've already cloned master and have a local version of that on my machine. If I pull branch A, checkout to branch B, and do another pull with branch B, do the codes from branch A and branch B get "merged" together? Meaning at since I pulled both of them once already, at any one point in time that I am working on a particular branch, am I working on code that is a combination of both branches? I would not think so. I would think that each branch that I'm working on has its own particular instance and is independent of other branches correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following sequence while in a repository containing two branches A and B, A and B should be independent

```
git checkout A
git pull MASTER A
git checkout B
git pull MASTER B
```

However, if you do something like this you'll end up merging A into B

```
git checkout B
git pull MASTER A
```

I think this might shed some light on what a branch is and how to do various workflows, as well as a lot of tips/tricks for using Git in general.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is

Answer (score 0):

As a best pratice when working with branches, I always set the target branch for a pull.

```
git checkout branchB
git pull origin branchB
```

You can if you like pull from branchA and merge with it too

```
 git checkout branchB
 git pull origin branchA
```

Depends in what you want to do. But pulling and merging another branch fron the server blindly is not the best thing to do. In this case you want to fetch look what branchA has to offer and merge after that with git merge or rebase.